# What libraries provide an implementation of multigrid?

Tags: pde, software, multigrid

I am working on numerical method of Multigrid. What's the available implementation(solver) (actually used in scientific computation) of multigrid method?

Comment: Are you asking about which libraries provide multigrid implementations, or are you asking about which multigrid methods are actually used in practice?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I am asking libraries used in practice(with MPI openMP or CUDA whatever). Can you give any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many libraries that provide widely used implementations of multigrid methods. Most of the available finite element libraries do to the best of my knowledge (certainly the one I work on, [deal.II](http://www.dealii.org/), does). There are also widely used implementations of algebraic multigrid methods, most notably from the ML and [hypre](http://acts.nersc.gov/hypre/) packages that you can most easily access via the [Trilinos](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/) and [PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/) projects.